# SQL join one time only

Tags: sql, join, select, window-functions

I have below situation

Table 1

```
Id          Sum
1           100
2           100
3           200
4           400
```

Table 2

```
ID          Sum
5           100
6           200
7           300
8           400
```

I want to write a query that joins between both tables and show me the matching one time only. The result should be

```
1     100     Match
2     100     Mismatch 
3     200     Match
4     300     Mismatch 
5     400     Match
```

I am using this query

```
select a.id, a.sum,b.id,b.sum,
CASE 
    when a.sum = b.sum then 'Match' 
    else 'Mismatch' 
end as Result 
from table1 a  LEFT OUTER join table2 b on a.sum = b.sum
```

The result is

```
    1     100    5     100     Match
    2     100    5     100     Match
    3     200    6     200     Match
    4     400    8     400     Match
```

Basically, this is a collection system. The system is saving the data automatically in table 2. When the employees do the real collection, they upload the data in table 1. Now I want to show a report that is showing the differences between collections based on the sum. So, if Employee inserted 100$ 2 times, I should show that the system captured this only once and there is 1 extra row in table 1

Comment: Please provide the query you are executing.

Comment: select * From Table1 A left outer join Table2 B on A.Sum=B.Sum

The result of this is 100 matching 2 times since the value exists in the second table.

Comment: if `id=1` matches because of having the same sum as `id=5` in the second table, then why `id=2` mismatches? revise your requirements

Comment: Please don't ask us to write your code. Show what you can do & expalin re being stuck. Clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: explain logic on which basis you are doing comparison.. 100 - match/mismatch is confusing

Comment: @mangusta let's say that this is a collection report. The system saved in table 2 100$ collected one time and the employee uploaded it in table 2 twice. I want to show that 100$ is collected one time as per the system and 2 times as per the employee.

Comment: what basis you want to differentiate  system generated and manually data?

Comment: @Always_a_learner based on the sum field. If 100$ appears once in the system, it should appear once in employee's collection records. Otherwise, I want to show a mismatch.

Comment: @ahmed as you want to show differences..check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to join on `id`?

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.sum, 
    case when t1.sum = t2.sum then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as result
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Alternatively, if `id`s do not math, you might want to use `row_number()`:

```
select 
    t1.id id1, 
    t1.sum sum1, 
    t2.id id2,
    t2.sum sum2,
    case when t1.sum = t2.sum then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as result
from (select t1.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from table1 t1) t1
inner join ((select t2.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from table2 t2) t2 
    on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Finally: if the count of rows in both table might be different, use a `full join` instead of an `inner join` (if your database supports it):

```
select 
    t1.id id1, 
    t1.sum sum1, 
    t2.id id2,
    t2.sum sum2,
    case when t1.sum = t2.sum then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as result
from (select t1.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from table1 t1) t1
full join (select t2.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from table2 t2) t2 
    on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: Now it is working. There was a small mistake in the query.

select 
    t1.id id1, 
    t1.sum sum1, 
    t2.id id2,
    t2.sum sum2,
    case when t1.sum = t2.sum then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as result
from (select t1.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from table1 t1) t1
full join (select t2.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from table2 t2) t2 
    on t2.rn = t1.rn

Comment: @ahmed: indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to highlight differences between two tables. you should group by sum and compare cont of sum. Use full outer join as you want to show differences of both sides as below :

```
select *,
CASE 
when a.cnt = b.cnt then 'Match' 
else 'Mismatch' 
end as Result from
(select sum,count(1) as cnt from table1 group by sum) a
full join
(select sum,count(1) as cnt from table2 group by sum) b
on a.sum=b.sum
```

[sql Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c024/15)

Output look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
select t1.id, t1.sum,
    CASE 
        when t1.sum = t2.sum then 'Match' 
        else 'Mismatch' 
    end
    as Compare
    from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: IDs won't match. I can't join by Id

Comment: by what do you want to join then?